# Broadcasting error with incompatible input/output sizes (PyTorch Wave-U-Net)

Tags: python, audio, deep-learning, pytorch, torchaudio

I'm trying to train a Wave-U-Net for mixing multitrack audio (8 mono stems to a stereo mixture) following the methodology of [this](https://www-aes-org.ezproxy.library.qmul.ac.uk/tmpFiles/elib/20220803/21023.pdf) paper, whereby:

> Each input consist of 121,843 samples or 2.76 seconds and the output corresponds to the center part of the inputs
> and consists of 89,093 samples or 2.02 seconds.

My net is:

```
class Waveunet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Waveunet, self).__init__()
        #self.enc_num_layers = 10
        #self.dec_num_layers = 10
        #self.enc_filter_size = 15
        #self.dec_filter_size = 5
        #self.input_channel = 2
        #self.nfilters = 24

        enc_channel_in = [8] + [min(10, (i + 1)) * 24 for i in range(9)]
        enc_channel_out = [min(10, (i + 1)) * 24 for i in range(10)]
        dec_channel_out = enc_channel_out[:10][::-1]
        dec_channel_in = [enc_channel_out[-1]*2 + 24] + [enc_channel_out[-i-1] + dec_channel_out[i-1] for i in range(1, 10)]

        self.encoder = nn.ModuleList()
        self.decoder = nn.ModuleList()

        for i in range(10):
            self.encoder.append(nn.Conv1d(enc_channel_in[i], enc_channel_out[i], 15))

        for i in range(10):
            self.decoder.append(nn.Conv1d(dec_channel_in[i], dec_channel_out[i], 5))

        self.middle_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(enc_channel_out[-1], enc_channel_out[-1] + 24, 15),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)
        )
        self.output_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(32, 2, kernel_size=1),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self,x):
        encoder = list()
        input = x

        # Downsampling
        for i in range(10):
            x = self.encoder[i](x)
            x = F.leaky_relu(x,0.2)
            encoder.append(x)
            x = x[:,:,::2]

        x = self.middle_layer(x)

        # Upsampling
        for i in range(10):
            x = F.interpolate(x, size=x.shape[-1]*2-1, mode='linear', align_corners=True)
            x = self.crop_and_concat(x, encoder[10 - i - 1])
            x = self.decoder[i](x)
            x = F.leaky_relu(x,0.2)

        # Concat with original input
        x = self.crop_and_concat(x, input)

        # Output prediction
        output = self.output_layer(x)
        return output

    def crop_and_concat(self, x1, x2):
        crop_x2 = self.crop(x2, x1.shape[-1])
        x = torch.cat([x1,crop_x2],dim=1)
        return x

    def crop(self, tensor, target_shape):
        # Center crop
        shape = tensor.shape[-1]
        diff = shape - target_shape
        crop_start = diff // 2
        crop_end = diff - crop_start
        return tensor[:,:,crop_start:-crop_end]
```

Checking the summary with my input size

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = Waveunet()
model = model.to(device)

from torchsummary import summary
summary(model, input_size=(8, 121843))
```

gives the correct output size (according to the paper):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv1d-1           [-1, 24, 121829]           2,904
            Conv1d-2            [-1, 48, 60901]          17,328
            Conv1d-3            [-1, 72, 30437]          51,912
            Conv1d-4            [-1, 96, 15205]         103,776
            Conv1d-5            [-1, 120, 7589]         172,920
            Conv1d-6            [-1, 144, 3781]         259,344
            Conv1d-7            [-1, 168, 1877]         363,048
            Conv1d-8             [-1, 192, 925]         484,032
            Conv1d-9             [-1, 216, 449]         622,296
           Conv1d-10             [-1, 240, 211]         777,840
           Conv1d-11              [-1, 264, 92]         950,664
        LeakyReLU-12              [-1, 264, 92]               0
           Conv1d-13             [-1, 240, 179]         605,040
           Conv1d-14             [-1, 216, 353]         492,696
           Conv1d-15             [-1, 192, 701]         391,872
           Conv1d-16            [-1, 168, 1397]         302,568
           Conv1d-17            [-1, 144, 2789]         224,784
           Conv1d-18            [-1, 120, 5573]         158,520
           Conv1d-19            [-1, 96, 11141]         103,776
           Conv1d-20            [-1, 72, 22277]          60,552
           Conv1d-21            [-1, 48, 44549]          28,848
           Conv1d-22            [-1, 24, 89093]           8,664
           Conv1d-23             [-1, 2, 89093]              66
             Tanh-24             [-1, 2, 89093]               0
================================================================
Total params: 6,183,450
Trainable params: 6,183,450
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 3.72
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 156.46
Params size (MB): 23.59
Estimated Total Size (MB): 183.77
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

However on training with Adam and L1 loss I get the following broadcasting error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [75], in <cell line: 17>()
     13 optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(),
     14                              lr=0.001)
     16 # train model
---> 17 train(net, train_loader, loss_fn, optimiser, device, 10)

Input In [72], in train(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimiser, device, epochs)
     20 for i in range(epochs):
     21     print(f"Epoch {i+1}")
---> 22     train_single_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimiser, device)
     23     for *vinputs, vtarget in data_loader:
     24         *vinputs, vtarget = vinputs[0].to(device), vinputs[1].to(device), vinputs[2].to(device), vinputs[3].to(device), vinputs[4].to(device), vinputs[5].to(device), vinputs[6].to(device), vinputs[7].to(device), vtarget.to(device)

Input In [72], in train_single_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimiser, device)
      7 # calculate loss
      8 prediction = model(cat)
----> 9 loss = loss_fn(prediction, target)
     11 # backpropagate error and update weights
     12 optimiser.zero_grad()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\TorchCuda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1127 # this function, and just call forward.
   1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\anaconda3\envs\TorchCuda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:96, in L1Loss.forward(self, input, target)
     95 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 96     return F.l1_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\TorchCuda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3248, in l1_loss(input, target, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   3245 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3246     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3248 expanded_input, expanded_target = torch.broadcast_tensors(input, target)
   3249 return torch._C._nn.l1_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))

File ~\anaconda3\envs\TorchCuda\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py:73, in broadcast_tensors(*tensors)
     71 if has_torch_function(tensors):
     72     return handle_torch_function(broadcast_tensors, tensors, *tensors)
---> 73 return _VF.broadcast_tensors(tensors)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (89093) must match the size of tensor b (121843) at non-singleton dimension 2
```